# How to interpret get_weights for Keras GRU?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, gru

I am unable to interpret the results of get_weights from a GRU layer. Here's my code -

```
#Modified from - https://machinelearningmastery.com/understanding-simple-recurrent-neural-networks-in-keras/
from pandas import read_csv
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, SimpleRNN, GRU
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(units = 2, input_shape = (3,1), activation = 'linear'))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear'))
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')

initial_weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()
print("Shape = ",initial_weights)
```

I am familiar with GRU concepts. In addition, I understand how the get_weights work for Keras Simple RNN layer, where the first array represents the input weights, the second the activation weights and the third the bias. However, I am lost with output of GRU, which is given below -

```
Shape =  [array([[-0.64266175, -0.0870676 , -0.25356603, -0.03685969,  0.22260845,
        -0.04923642]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.01929092, -0.4932567 ,  0.3723044 , -0.6559699 , -0.33790302,
         0.27062896],
       [-0.4214194 ,  0.46456426,  0.27233726, -0.00461334, -0.6533575 ,
        -0.32483965]], dtype=float32), array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)]
```

I am assuming it has something to do with GRU gates.

Update:7/4 - This [page](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/layers/rnn/gru.py#L946) says that keras GRU has 3 gates, update, reset and output. However, based on [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/illustrated-guide-to-lstms-and-gru-s-a-step-by-step-explanation-44e9eb85bf21), GRU shouldn't have the output gate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way I know would be to track the `add_weight()` calls in the [`build()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/layers/rnn/gru.py#L174) function of the `GRUCell`.

Let's take an example model,

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
     tf.keras.layers.GRU(32, input_shape=(5, 10), name='gru'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
    ]
)
```

How we'll print some metadata about what's returned by `weights = model.get_layer('gru').get_weights()`. Which gives,

```
Number of arrays in weights: 3
Shape of each array in weights: [(10, 96), (32, 96), (2, 96)]
```

Let's go back to what weights defined by the `GRUCell`. We got,

```
self.kernel = self.add_weight(
    shape=(input_dim, self.units * 3),
    ...
)
self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
    shape=(self.units, self.units * 3),
    ...
)

    ...
    bias_shape = (2, 3 * self.units)
    self.bias = self.add_weight(
        shape=bias_shape,
        ...
    )
```

This is what you're seeing as weights (in that order). Here's why they are shaped like this. GRU computations are outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_recurrent_unit).

[image: GRU computations]

The first matrix in `weights` (of shape `[10, 96]`) is a concatenation of `Wz|Wr|Wh` (in that order). Each of these is a `[10, 32]` sized tensor. Concatenation gives a `[10, 32*3=96]` sized tensor.

Similarly, the second matrix is a concatenation of `Uz|Ur|Uh`. Each of these is a `[32, 32]` sized tensor which becomes `[32, 96]` after concatenation.
You can see how they break this combined weight matrix to each of `z`, `r` and `h` components [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/layers/rnn/gru.py#L235).

Finally the bias. It contains 2 biases i.e. `[2, 96]` sized tensor; [`input_bias` and `recurrent_bias`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/layers/rnn/gru.py#L223). Again, biases from all gates/weights are combined to a single tensor. Typically, only the `input_bias` is used. But if you have `reset_after` (decides how the reset gate is applied) set to `True`, then the `recurrent_bias` gets used. It's an implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please tell me what's w_z|w_r|w_h? I checked the Wikipedia link you posted and even that didn't have the information.

Comment: `W_z` is the input weight matrix of the update gate, `W_r` is the input weight matrix of the reset gate, `W_h` is the input weight matrix of the candidate activation (denoted by `\tilde{h}`) computation step. The notation `W|X|Y` simply denotes concatenation of W, X and Y on column axis.